# Extract key, type and nullability from Typescript interface

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-proptypes

I am new to Typescript and have recently been converting a React Javascript Component Library to Typescript. When initially setting up the library a few months back, I added a component that leveraged [this awesome package](https://github.com/reactjs/react-docgen) to extract a Component's prop-types and render a table of them on our doc site.

I have since converted our old `propTypes` declarations to Typescript's native `interface` equivalents. I want to be able to write something that can parse the prop key, types and nullability indicators from the interfaces, for use in a new table.

Have done alot of reading on the subject and am unsure if it is even possible due to the fact that Typescript declarations are read only at runtime, any help is appreciated!

Comment: Typescript declarations are compiled away at compile time, and not available at run time

Comment: To @TomCumming's point, you won't be able to access your TypeScript interfaces at runtime. You'll either have to use [a tool](https://github.com/YousefED/typescript-json-schema) that statically generates the data you need at compile time, or switch to a TypeScript-based documentation generator. Perhaps something like [TypeDoc](https://typedoc.org)?

Comment: Using mapped and conditional types you can construct types so constrained that they have a single valid value that represents the type, nullability and optionality of a interface properties. This will be checked by the compiler so even if the data is duplicated it will not go out of sync. Nullability and optionality are easy. For the type things get more complicated. For primitives we can get the string representation, the question is what do you want to put in for classes/other interfaces/ function signatures. If you answer that question and are interested in this  solution  I can provide it